# Get Parent of custom TextBox control

Tags: c#, controls

When creating a custom control which extends TextBox, inside the OnCreateControl() override, Parent is null. When extending other controls such as Button, it isn't null. I am checking with the following code and adding it to a form and various container controls:

```
protected override void OnCreateControl()
{
    base.OnCreateControl();
    MessageBox.Show((Parent == null).ToString()); //True when extending TextBox, False when extending Button
}
```

What can I do to retrieve the Parent of the control when it is added to another control, ensuring that the same code will work regardless of which control I extend?

Comment: I would think overriding the OnParentChanged would be more appropriate.

Comment: This works. Unfortunately the TextBox control seems to behave very differently to other controls in terms of painting, so i'll probably be scratching the idea to begin with.

Comment: Your question never mentions painting as an issue.  The TextBox does not use the Paint event.

Comment: At least I learned to use OnParentChanged. What can I do to modify the appearance of a custom TextBox, as I would any other control?